# It is just like if the UI has a sort of priority on the active cell in the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

In a database programme I use very often some functions that rely on these 2 methods :

```
  var activerow = sh.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var activecol = sh.getActiveSelection().getColumnIndex();
```

which are very basic function ;-)  very recently (I don't know exactly when, I didn't check it for a while) I began to have reproductible issue with these 2 methods : **if an Ui is 'in focus' they return a value of 1**

That is at least what It looks like but it is completely abnormal and not logic so I'm asking for some people to look at this and tell me if I'm wrong (and a bit 'fool') and missing something obvious (well I would hope so ;-)

This is an [test sheet I shared][1] , I explain everything on the sheet and the script is very basic too for anybody who knows about UIs.  There is an onOpen menu that resets the sheet and creates a menu for your confort ;-)  The problem occurs when a button is pressed in the UI (both of them).

Thanks for your help

note : same issue on Chrome & Safari

EDIT REMOVED, was probably a browser issue on my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently an issue where the activeSheet / Range / Cell are being set to cell A1 of the first sheet once you enter a server handler. You can track the progress of the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1476

Comment: thanks, I didn't see it in the issue tracker (don't know why), sorry about that :-)